# How to set a global formatter for Calendar and Date in a Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

In a Spring Boot app I want to set a global formatter in Spring MVC for *Calendar* and *Date* values.

I have found the *spring.mvc.date-format* property which allows to set the global formatter, but only for the *Date* type. As I want to use the same format for the *Calendar* type, I have created the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  private Formatter<Date> dateFormatter;

  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    if (dateFormatter != null) {
      registry.addFormatterForFieldType(Calendar.class, this.dateFormatter);
    }
  }
}
```

It is reusing the same formatter for Dates created by the Spring Boot autoconfiguration for Spring MVC, and it works as expected.

My question is: Is this the correct way to do it, or am I missing something? Shouldn't it be handled this way already in the Spring Boot autoconfiguration, setting the same formatter for Date and Calendar types?

**EDIT:** I have found the previous configuration class fails when you have tests that don't load the Spring Boot application (using *@SpringApplicationConfiguration*), as the Boot autoconfiguration is not performed and then the dateFormatter is not available. Changing the *@Autowired* annotation to *@Autowired(required = false)* solves the problem, but I'm still not sure of the "correctness" of the solution.

Updated configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired(required = false)
  private Formatter<Date> dateFormatter;

  @Override
  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    if (dateFormatter != null) {
      registry.addFormatterForFieldType(Calendar.class, this.dateFormatter);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @SpringApplicationConfiguration declaration does not allow you to declare Date formater in Spring MVC configuration. Am I correct with my understanding? Is there any error you receive?

Comment: No, I don't have any error. The problem I see with the solution is the dependency on the spring boot autoconfiguration. I had to add the _required=false_ parameter to the _Autowired_ annotation to avoid errors in some tests, and I have the feeling the solution is not fully correct. Maybe it would be better to avoid using the _spring.mvc.date-format_ property and register the date formatter by myself for Date and Calendar types.